# Getting error while try to write gif image to buffer

Tags: vips

I am using PHP libvips library when I am using this function **writeToBuffer** for write to buffer the image it gives me below types of error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Jcupitt\Vips\Exception: magicksave_buffer: libMagick error: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/blob.c/ImagesToBlob/2413
```

**Note - This error occurs only when my image type is gif**

```
$imagePathInfo = pathinfo($inputFileName);
$imgExtension = $imagePathInfo['extension'];
$img = Vips\Image::newFromFile($inputFileName, ['access' => 'sequential']);
$img = $img->writeToBuffer('.' . $imgExtension);
```

[image: Image which I am trying]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default libvips will only load the first frame of an animation. To load all frames, set the `n` parameter (number of pages) to -1. Use:

```php
$img = Vips\Image::newFromFile($inputFileName, [
    'access' => 'sequential', 
    'n' => -1
]);
```

libvips 8.11 uses imagemagick to write GIF images. You need to tell imagemagick what format to write in with the `format` parameter, eg.:

```php
$img = $img->writeToBuffer('.' . $imgExtension, [
    'format' => $imgExtension
]);
```

libvips 8.12 (due by the end of Nov 2021) will automatically pass the correct format value to imagemagick, and also has a dedicated and much faster GIF writer.

Comment: If I pass image extension, does it works for all images like I have on common function in my class, which accepts the file name (with jpg, jpeg extension etc..). My question is

Is the last solution which you gave will work for all types of images?

Comment: No, you'll need to handle GIFs as a separate case for now. libvips 8.12 fixes this.